# jw player size is not appropriate to video resolution

Tags: jwplayer

i have a problem in jw player. i set my player height = 225 width = 400. It is exact 16:9 ratio. If i play any 400x225 resolution video or exact 16:9 ratio video. i get vertical bars at both sides of the player about 5mm each. For ref image is given below. how to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.  [image]

Comment: The problem is your control bar. It is included as part of the height. The solution is to change the dock to disappear after play.

Answer (score 8):

please add this stretching:"exactfit"  in your java script code ,

I had the same issue and after add above line now it is fine.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
'flashplayer': '/path to player.swf',
'file': '/path to video.mp4',
'controlbar': 'bottom',
 stretching:"exactfit",
'width': '600',
'height': '370',
'skin': '.../path to modieus.zip',
'image': '../path to image screenshot'
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

you should add around "20px" to the player height , because the player controller (play , pause , timer, ...) will be included with the 225px height ,

so increase the height of the player to 245px

Comment: what you are telling is i need to add width or subtract height. but the point is player height & width is same as video resolution. Then why i am getting vertical bars?

Comment: thats the point , I think that you should add 25px to the height of the player . try doing that.

Comment: I have that solution already. Instead of that i adjusted the video resolution about 25px to fit in the player. The player works for commercial here. so i could not change player height or width. Its already in 16:9 ratio. The proper 16:9 video should fit in proper 16:9 player without vertical bars.

Comment: Arrabi is right. When you set the width to 400 and height to 225, your actual video play area is 400x200 (roughly). So to get the video play area to a 16:9 ratio you would have to add 20-25px.

Answer (score 2):

player height and width is unfortunately not equal to video resolution.  The video resolution is determined by jw player by reading the video metadata.  If the size is not specified there, it defaults to 4:3 aspect ratio, and adds the black bars your seeing.  I don't believe adjusting the video player size, as suggested above, will not work to display the video correctly - it just adjusts the frame size.  I wish I had an answer for this outside of embedding the size data into the video, but unfortunately do not.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this problem. Go to the advanced settings of the JW Player and set the smooth value to true. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was this... Keep in mind I am using the JW Embedder. My video player skin is modieus and my videos are 16:9 aspect ratio. My width is 600px. The 16:9 ratio applied here means my height is 338px so this is the dimension you set for your image if wanting a screenshot to fill the player before playing like me. Depending on your player, you need to set a different height to accommodate the controlbar. In my case, the controlbar needed 32px so the height I set in my jwplayer is now 370px.

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': '/path to player.swf',
    'file': '/path to video.mp4',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '600',
    'height': '370',
    'skin': '.../path to modieus.zip',
    'image': '../path to image screenshot'
     });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Standard                           Resolution          Aspect Ratio
2. 480p                                  640×480            4:3 (unscaled)
3. Rec. 601                            720×480            4:3/16:9
4. Rec. 601 plus a quarter     800×480            4:3/16:9
5. Wide 480p                         852×480            16:9 (unscaled)

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jwplayer("PlayMP4Video").setup({
            file: "video/kuru_fasulye_reklami.MP4",
            flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
            width:"800",
            height:"480",
            image: "image/background.jpg"
        });
    });
</script>
```